# What is the most efficient way to store a series of values with unknown size?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, hashtable, glib

I have a function (say, named `next_entity`), that generates size_t values. The function acts as a generator, that is, it produces a new value on each call, and, finally, returns 0 as a sentinel.

In another function, that calls `next_entity`, I need to store the values somewhere. I don't know the amount of the values before I receive the sentinel, so I cannot `malloc` or statically allocate an array to contain these values before they come.

The thing is, that after the sentinel comes, the only thing I need to do with the values is to save them to a file, but with no repetitions, that is, each value must occur only once.

After that, the values are no more needed.

I tried to use `GHashTable` from `glib.h` during the iteration, to store the values as the keys, but the problem with `GHashTable` is that the pointers to the keys passed to the function g_hash_table_insert must remain alive during the lifecycle of the hash-table, so I have to do kind of `malloc(sizeof(size_t))` for each new value.

It works, but it seems to be quite inefficient, because `malloc` is time-consuming.

Is there any better way to do that?

I can post the real code if it is needed, but I don't think the problem is about the code.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: What kind of values next_entity generates? sample values would be helpful. if it can be treated as an integer bouded in some range I've got an idea, but doesnt work for any generic type.

Comment: 321681232;321682368;321681472;326130336;326165232;325443504; 321680432;324998096;320391552;326178192;326178160;321680208; 325442128;324791472;326130304;326182544;325030320;326160816; 321680880;325442192;

Comment: @sanjeevakumar-hiremath Do you mean bit-array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys in a hash table are a void*, and a void* is always at least as large as a size_t.

All you need to do is, instead of malloc(sizeof(size_t)), use g_hash_table_new(NULL,NULL) to use g_direct_hash as the hash method. Then do this:

```
g_hash_table_replace(table, GSIZE_TO_POINTER(value), GSIZE_TO_POINTER(value))
```

To iterate over keys, use GPOINTER_TO_SIZE to get back to the size_t.

You can always do this for any integer type, instead of malloc'ing it. (use GINT_TO_POINTER, GUINT_TO_POINTER, instead of GSIZE_TO_POINTER when appropriate)

Comment: Yes, it works great! Thank you very much, your answer is definitely the most useful so far. I just didn't know that g_hash_table_new(NULL,NULL) enables g_direct_hash as the hash method.

Comment: The only wrong thing: GPOINTER_TO_SIZE actually casts to `gsize`, not to `size_t`, and these types differ in size. I did with simple type casts like `(void*)value` and `(size_t)key`.

Comment: gsize and size_t should not be different in size... if so it's some bug in glib or something. But yeah, just casts are probably fine here, the glib macros are more paranoia/future-proofness than actually necessary.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe, the thing is that I have x86_64 gcc and (maybe) both i386 and x86_64 glib... So, glib headers may be for i386, I'm to sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you data size is not gigabytes, you can do with a dynamically array, which you double in size with `realloc()`ing every time you run out of space. With this strategy only log(N) reallocations will have to happen.

In C++, for example, a lot of `std::vector` implementations usually do just that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any way to evaluate the limit? Does GArray from glib act like this?

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij On the second thought I removed this from my answer. By the looks of it, the usual implementation relies on system failing to allocate memory. By this point you try to handle out of memory error or get killed by the OS (Linux). You should probably handle any limits in the application.

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij Looking at glib source code, GArray appears to employ the same strategy.

Comment: What do you think about Jim Balter's answer?

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested realloc. Instead of that, consider using a linked list of malloced blocks, where each block contains a largish array of numbers; when you fill up a block, allocate another one and link the previous one to it ... or link it to the previous one and then reverse the list before outputing them. The point is that you don't need to store your values in contiguous memory, so you don't need to use realloc. realloc copies the previous array, which you can avoid and which will be slow for very large arrays, and it could even run out of memory if it can't find a large enough contiguous block, whereas allocating individual blocks is more resilient. The downside is that it takes more work to manage the linked list.

====
Edit for GHashTable usage:

Store your value into the array and pass the address of that element to the hash routine ... if it's not already present, advance the array pointer. To output the values, just enumerate the keys from the hash table. The linked list of arrays is only needed for deallocating them. If this is all the program does, then you don't even need to maintain a linked list; you can just allocate arrays as you need them, and they will all get deallocated when your program exits.

Comment: I like this (+1). But how are you going to eliminate duplicates from several blocks of numbers?

Comment: @Pupikov-Zadnij -- I've edited this, adding some more info, since you selected it. If you need more info about managing such a linked list, let me know.

Comment: @pmg good point that I overlooked ... but the same problem exists for a realloced array. To avoid duplicates, the OP really needs a hash table or search tree. Best to use an available package.

Comment: @pmg -- I use GHashTable to eliminate the duplicates, the thing is, that the it cannot _store_ the values @Jim Balter -- thank you in advance, isn't `GSList` from `glib.h` enough in this case?

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij I don't recall the details of GSList but, from your description above and here, it sounds like using it to eliminate duplicates but storing the values in either my linked list or a realloced array would solve your problem.

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij I've edited my answer to include info about using the hash table ... please see.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I actually wanted. No, it is not all the program does, so I need to deallocate the arrays. The only question that still remains is - what is better - to take the keys from the hash-table into the resulting array using `g_hash_table_foreach`, or to `memcpy` them from the arrays within the linked list?

Comment: I think this is far more complicated than required. Just don't alloc your size_t as the hash keys, use them directly. i.e. no malloc, just a cast to void* using GSIZE_TO_POINTER() for portability.

Comment: @Pupkov-Zadnij @Havoc I'm not sure about the details of GHashTable, but Havoc may well be right -- if you are in control of hashing and comparison, then you should be able to pass the values in and out as "pointers" without ever dereferencing them.

Comment: P.S. If that works for you, be sure to accept Havoc's answer rather than mine.

Comment: It doesn't work - I tried it even before asking this question. g_hash_table_insert tries to dereference the pointer to calculate the hash function. Update: hmm, I didn't try to use g_direct_hash as hash method, so, theoretically, Havoc may be rigth...

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to multiply the space used by a constant (2, 1.69, 1.618, 1.5, ...).

I like the golden ratio :)

```
arr = malloc(elems * sizeof *arr);
{
    /* ... */
    elems = elems * 13 / 8; /* approximate golden ratio */
    tmparr = realloc(arr, elems * sizeof *arr);
    if (tmparr == NULL) /* deal with error */;
    arr = tmparr;
    /* ... */
}
free(arr);
```

Comment: Looks fantastic, but what is the magic of the golden ration? Why is it better to multiply by 13/8 and not by 8/13, for example?

Comment: Well ... to grow the array you have to multiply by a number bigger than 1 :)

Comment: And the golden ration is no more magic than `2`. I'm sure there is a optimum multiplicand for general use (I don't know what it is). The idea is to minimize the number of `realloc` calls **and** minimize 'wasted' memory. As I said: I just like the golden ratio.

Comment: :) :) I actually mean - why by 13/8 and not by any other number bigger than 1?

Comment: There is no generally optimum multiplicand -- it's a tradeoff between the number of reallocs and the risk of running out of memory (or address space). 2 is good because it's easy ... 13/8 seems to just add obscurity for obscurity's sake.

Comment: The golden ratio *is* magic.  Below it you can reuse the previously freed memory to fill the current request, over it you can't (mathematical derivation -- with text in french -- is here: http://bourguet.org/v2/cs/realloc/; note that the nearer your are to the golden ratio, the more resizing are needed before it is possible).  13/8 is just above the golden ratio, so you never can reuse the freed memory to fill up the request. Personnaly I like 1.5, just add half of want is currently allocated.

Comment: @AProgrammer realloc either has sufficient free memory contiguous to the allocated block, in which it just extends it, or it doesn't, in which case it frees the block, does a first (usually; sometimes best) fit for the allocation size and copies the old array. The golden ratio doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Thanks @AProgrammer. I have been using `13 / 8` because of the nano seconds saved with the division by 8. I chose 13 and 8 from Fibonacci numbers without realizing the importance of the ratio being above or below the golden ratio. I'll be using `8 / 5` or `21 / 13` from now on :)

Comment: @Jim Balter, I agree that the effect is less important when using realloc than when you are allocating fresh memory and then copy.

Comment: You'd normally just use GArray in GLib, rather than manually growing a malloc block with realloc